# Same footnote spacing than baselineskip

Tags: footnotes, line-spacing

I would like to know why exactly

`\setlength{\footnotesep}{\baselineskip}`

Is still not producing the same vertical spacing between footnotes than between lines inside footnotes themselves.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin={2.5cm,2.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Modifier for vspace between lines (=\baselinestretch*\baselineskip)
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

% Modifies the space over footnote line
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{\baselineskip}

% Modifies the space between notes in footnotes 
\setlength{\footnotesep}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2][1-5]}

\lipsum[2][4-7]\footnote{\lipsum[1][2-3]}

\lipsum[3][1-2]\footnote{\lipsum[3][1]}

\lipsum[4]\footnote{\lipsum[4][2-4]}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

I know it is a tiny difference, almost imperceptible, but I think it can be perceived.

I guess this is relative to footnotes super index mark, which is a little upper than the top of the line.

My question actually is ... Could this be fixed with no using such an arbitrary factor as `.9`? Since if I use

`\setlength{\footnotesep}{.9\baselineskip}`

It seems to be fixed.

My idea is to have the same footnote step than line skip. Or eventually the same than paragraph skip even.

Comment: You are using the `\baselineskip` as for the regular font size, but typically fooitnotes are set using the `\footnotesize` font, which has a different `\baselineskip`. Try enclosing your changes within a `footnotesize` environment.

Comment: I don't know if I'm getting you properly. Are you talking about `\addtolength` and `\setlength`? In the preamble? inside a `footnotesize` environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should patch `\footnotesize` to use the normal baseline skip. Plus defining `\footnotesep` to be 70% of the normal baseline skip.

Here I use `\regexpatch`, so there is no need to copy the definition from the suitable `.clo` file and it works for any main size option (`10pt`, `11pt`, `12pt`) without manual intervention.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\bodybaselineskip}
\makeatletter
\regexpatchcmd{\footnotesize}
  {(\c{footnotesize}.).*?(\c{abovedisplayskip})}
  {\1\c{bodybaselineskip}\2}
  {}{}
\setlength{\bodybaselineskip}{\normalbaselineskip}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.7\normalbaselineskip}}
\makeatother

\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2][1-5]}

\lipsum[2][4-5]\footnote{\lipsum[1][2-3]}

\lipsum[3][1-2]\footnote{\lipsum[3][1]}

\lipsum[4][1-5]\footnote{\lipsum[4][2-4]\the\baselineskip}\the\baselineskip

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you just want to adjust the spacing *between* footnotes, it's less cumbersome:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\linespread{1.5}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  {\footnotesize\global\footnotesep=0.7\baselineskip}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2][1-5]}

\lipsum[2][4-5]\footnote{\lipsum[1][2-3]}

\lipsum[3][1-2]\footnote{\lipsum[3][1]}

\lipsum[4][1-5]\footnote{\lipsum[4][2-4]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can consider using `setspace` that leaves compact spacing in footnotes.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setstretch{1.5}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2][1-5]}

\lipsum[2][4-5]\footnote{\lipsum[1][2-3]}

\lipsum[3][1-2]\footnote{\lipsum[3][1]}

\lipsum[4][1-5]\footnote{\lipsum[4][2-4]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll try and give you the feedback, but seems nice. What's the difference between `\linespread{}` and `\baselinestretch{}`?

Comment: maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. I don't want the same space between footnotes than between lines in normal text; I want the same space between footnotes than between lines in footnotes text.

Comment: @JFernan I added two alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `\baselineskip` as for the regular font size but typically footnotes are set with the `footnotesize` font, which has a different `\baselineskip`.

Instead of your plain

```
\setlength{\footnotesep}{\baselineskip}
```

use

```
{\footnotesize \setlength{\footnotesep}{\baselineskip}}
```

Comment: This is shrinking even more the space between footnotes.

Comment: @JFernan So it does; I didn't test it. I find your concern imperceptible so just go with your fix of `0.9\baselineskip`. I agree that your problem cones from the elevated footnote number.